# syncfusion ejs scheduler angular

Tags: angular

i'm trying to use ejs-schedule in my project but i'm getting this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at Week.formatDateRange (ej2-schedule.es2015.js:18158)
    at Week.getDateRangeText (ej2-schedule.es2015.js:18124)
    at Render.updateHeader (ej2-schedule.es2015.js:11841)
    at Render.initializeLayout (ej2-schedule.es2015.js:11821)
    at Render.render (ej2-schedule.es2015.js:11742)
    at ScheduleComponent.initializeView (ej2-schedule.es2015.js:14345)
    at ScheduleComponent.renderElements (ej2-schedule.es2015.js:14160)
    at ScheduleComponent.initializeResources (ej2-schedule.es2015.js:14142)
    at ScheduleComponent.render (ej2-schedule.es2015.js:13974)
    at ScheduleComponent.appendTo (ej2-base.es2015.js:6850)
```

my html is simple i've just added the tag

```
<ejs-schedule #scheduleObj></ejs-schedule>
```

and in the ts file `@ViewChild('scheduleObj', {static: true}) public schedule: ScheduleComponent;`